# Alternative VBA code for Mac to avoid ActiveX limitation, to dynamically generate .txt/html file based on excel inputs

Tags: excel, vba, macos, function, filesystemobject

I run a golf deals website where I share five golf deals each day.

I created a VBA script on PC to automatically generate a .txt newsletter file (formatted as HTML) to upload into my mail client. I fill in parameters for each deal and the tool opens the base .txt file, does a find and replace based on two columns and then spits out a .txt for that day.

As an example.
Assuming the first column includes |*DEAL1TITLE*| and the second "Callaway Golf Balls".
The code will search the base .txt file for |*DEAL1TITLE*|, replace with the latter and then create a net-new file.
This repeats for ~40 different words/phrases.

I want to port the code to a Mac.

We experience

> "Run-time error '429': ActiveX component can't create object"

when calling `CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")` because FileSystemObject is only in the Windows scripting library.

Is there a Mac VBA workaround (research says not an easy one)? Or an alternative script to get the same result between both PC and Mac?
I would like to stay within VBA as there are several other outputs that the Excel tool generates.

```vb
Sub EmailCreate()
    
    Dim wsPath As String
    Dim Dealcount As String
    Dim Inputfile As String
    wsPath = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path
    Dealcount = Sheet7.Range("A1").Text
    
    Inputfile = wsPath & "\DGS_Daily_Template_" & Dealcount & "_deals.txt"
    
    Dim txt As String, arr, c As Long
    
    arr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet5").Range("C2:D51").Value
    txt = GetContent(Inputfile)
    For c = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        txt = Replace(txt, arr(c, 1), arr(c, 2))
    Next c
    
    PutContent wsPath & "\DGS_Email_" & Format(Now(), "DD-MMM-YYYY") & ".txt", txt
        
End Sub
```

Supporting functions

```vb
Function GetContent(f As String) As String
GetContent = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject"). _
              OpenTextFile(f, 1).ReadAll()
End Function

Sub PutContent(f As String, content As String)
    CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject"). _
                  OpenTextFile(f, 2, True).Write content
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two obvious options. Use Excel's file functions or use the older VBA file functions.

Excel - See `Workbook.SaveAs` (also `Worksheet.SaveAs`) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas

VBA - See `Open` statement - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/open-statement

> Enables input/output (I/O) to a file.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> Open pathname For mode [ Access access ] [ lock ] As [ # ] filenumber [ Len = reclength ]
> ```

The VBA specification states

> The host application in conjunction with the VBA implementation is
> also responsible for providing the  mapping of the VBA file I/O model
> to an application specific or platform file storage mechanism.

So whoever ported VBA to Excel for the Mac has to do the above. That of course is Macrosoft's Mac team.